# Website stopped working after whole site restoration, PHP Warning: session_start(): Failed to read session data

Tags: php, joomla

we had a fully working Joomla site but it was hacked a few hours ago. We asked our host to restore the files and they did, however the site stopped working altogether and they refuse to help us.

The logs have the following:

```
PHP Warning:  session_start(): Failed to read session data: user (path: /tmp) in /home/host/public_html/libraries/joomla/session/handler/native.php on line 260
```

Apparently that means that our site isn't able to reach our databases.
We are sure the host remains as localhost, and the passwords remain as they were, which means the ports probably changed. Is there a way to know which are the current ports that we should put at

```
public $memcached_server_host = 'localhost';
public $memcached_server_port = '11211';
public $redis_server_host = 'localhost';
public $redis_server_port = '6379';
```

In our configuration.php file?

Comment: If you are doing Joomla development, you owe it to yourself to have a [joomla.se] Stack Exchange account.  After extending your Stack Exchange account to this niche community, if you would like to have your question migrated there, just ping me and I can help with that.

Comment: Once I get you and Toivo to join JSE, I intend to request that this Joomla question be migrated to JSE.

Comment: Where did you go @Alex ?

Answer (score 1):

The details posted earlier are not related to the database.

The following lines in the file configuration.php define the database connection:

```
public $dbtype = 'mysqli';
public $host = 'localhost:3308';
public $user = 'database-user';
public $password = 'database-password';
public $db = 'database-name';
public $dbprefix = 'prefx_';
```

The variable $host can contain the IP address or the FQDN of the database server.  The port, for example 3306 or 3308, is optional.

Comment: Excellent to see you in the Stack Exchange network Toivo, please join us at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange as well -- we can you use your expertise there too.